# How can I delete a former MTP directory, which now gives me input/output error whenever I try?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, filenames, mtp

I have `~/srv/mtp`, which I do not remember how I created. It was back when I was trying to set up a MTP mountpoint using various tools for that.

Currently I can't do anything to the directory.

```
○ file mtp
mtp: ERROR: cannot open `mtp' (Input/output error)cannot read `mtp' (Is a directory)

○ ll | grep mtp
ls: cannot access mtp: Input/output error
d????????? ? ?  ?          ?            ? mtp

○ rm -rf mtp
rm: cannot remove ‘mtp’: Is a directory

○ sudo rm -rf mtp
[sudo] password for sh: 
rm: cannot remove ‘mtp’: Is a directory
```

Moreover, thunar can't even list `~/srv`, which is the directory containing mtp, and which I visit quite often.

How can I fix that?

EDIT: in the output of `mount` it's mentioned as

```
   jmtpfs on /home/sh/srv/mtp type fuse.jmtpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Comment: Didn't you meant " **ssh** at wh5-1-5shamots in ~/srv ", in the first line of your code block?

Comment: Type `mount` and add the output to your question. This sort of thing is usually the result of a borked FS mount.

Comment: @Kira, thank you for bringing that to my attention, just a pasting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a FUSE fs mounted on the mountpoint, you use the ordinary FUSE unmount method:

```
fusermount -u /home/sh/srv/mtp
```

If that fails, you can try:

```
fusermount -u -z /home/sh/srv/mtp
```